# Is there a way to return a dictionary value without quotations?

Tags: python, dictionary, return

Sorry if this is somewhere out there but I just couldn't find a solution to what I was looking for. I want to return the value of my dictionary without the quotations and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
def read_wiktionary():
 answer = dict()
 f = open('wiktionary.txt', 'r')
 for line in f:
      word,value = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
      answer[word] = (value)
 return answer
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output? Its difficult to be sure what you mean when you say without quotations.

Comment: When you print a string value, it usually prints with quotations to indicate it's a string. The actual value of the string doesn't contain those quotes. Can you clarify what you need `answer` for and what isn't working?

Comment: >>> freq = read_wiktionary()
>>> freq['the']
56271872.0
>>> freq['my']
3277699.0

Comment: It should output like the above output, I'm getting the same outputs but with quotations.

Comment: Right Karin, but i am trying to return a dictionary value. Which I assumed would not return as a string.

Comment: That's because the line you read from the file is a string and ```value``` is stored as string in the dictionary. You can do ```answer[word] = float(value)```, which will store value as float (instead of string).

Answer (score 1):

The quotation is just used as a separator between different keys and values so it cannot be removed.The quotation doesn't affect your values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When you read a file, everything is read as a string. To get a float value, you'll need to cast it to a float.

```
def read_wiktionary():
    answer = dict()
    f = open('wiktionary.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        word, value = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
        answer[word] = float(value)
    return answer
```

As an aside, it's generally good practice to use `with` to open a file so that it will automatically be closed when it exits the block. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

So, I would suggest:

```
def read_wiktionary():
    answer = {}
    with open('wiktionary.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            word, value = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
            answer[word] = float(value)
    return answer
```